# Taking the mean of a column within a function and a for loop

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stat

I have the below function :

```
  compute_treatment_effects <- function(dataset, outcome, baseline_outcome, 
                                      covariates, 
                                      standardize){
  
  
  baseline_covariates <- c(baseline_outcome, covariates)
  
    
  dataset <- dataset %>%
    mutate(treat =ifelse(treatment_group == "trt", 1, 
                           ifelse(treatment_group == "control", 0, NA))) %>%
    filter(!is.na(treat))  
    
  if (standardize){
    dataset[,outcome] <- (dataset[,outcome] - mean(dataset[dataset$treat==0,outcome], na.rm=TRUE))/
      sd(dataset[dataset$treat==0,outcome], na.rm=TRUE)
  }
}
```

Now the issue, is whenever it gets to the standardization procedure, I get an error :

*"Error in is.data.frame(x) :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(dataset[dataset$treat == 0, outcome], na.rm = TRUE*)"

I am really not sure why this is the case, I dont believe the syntax is wrong anywhere ?

Here is an example of a dataframe to use with the code:

```
dataframe <- data.frame("var1" = c(1, 2, 5, 1, 642, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9, NA, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ),
                 "Var2"  = c(1, 3, 5, 1, 642, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ), 
                 "var3"   = c(1, 2, 635, 9, NA, 1, 2, 5, NA, NA, 12, NA, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
                 "var4"  = c(1, 21, 15, 19, NA, 1, 26656, 56,6 , NA, 512, NA, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
                 "cov1" =  c(1, 22,335, 29, NA, NA, NA, 645, NA, NA, 12, NA, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
                 "cov2" =  c(44251, 2322,5, 29, 45, 35, 42, 645, 55, 525, NA, NA, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
                 "cov3" =  c(154, 2552,35, 53529, 5, 3, 53542, 645, 25, 2, 12, 23, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))


dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  mutate(treatment_group = ifelse(var3 == 2, "trt", ifelse(var3 == 10, "control", NA)))
dataset <- dataframe
outcome <- "Var2"
baseline_outcome <- "var1"
covariates = c("cov1", "cov2","cov3")
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Your function shows only an `if`.. What would be the `else` case.  Also, it may be better to `return` the object

Comment: Yes sorry, I have put only the beginning of the function, it is much longer, it should return the dataset, but for now really, the main issue is with the standardize procedure.
In fact, if I just run  "mean(dataset[dataset$treat==0,outcome], na.rm=TRUE)" it tells me "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" even outside the function...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error with your function.  it works fine.  I added `return(dataset)` but even without that it is working fine

Comment: Could it be an issue with R version?

Comment: I used `R 4.1.1.`

Comment: `> compute_treatment_effects(dataset, outcome, baseline_outcome, covariates, standardize = TRUE) %>% str
'data.frame': 12 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ var1           : num  2 1 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ Var2           : num  -Inf NA NaN NaN NaN ...
 ...`

Comment: This is so weird.... i am not sure what is going on

Comment: Is this error on your larger data or in the reproducible example you posted

Comment: This will result in `error` if you have a `data.table` or `tibble` becuase the `,` wouldn't give a vector as you intend

Comment: But the values of the var2 variable are weird because they should all be real, since essentially i am standardising those values accross groups...

Comment: Can you try the code fix as in the solution below.

Comment: So @akrun, when I try it with my real dataframe, it does tell me : " Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' "

Comment: I believe the issue is with your data.frame class.  Can you checkk `class(dataset)`. It should be either tibble or data.table because I was able to replicate the same error when I convert to tibble.  The `[, outcome]` still returns a tibble with a single column and not a vector and `mean` expects a vector

Comment: Thank you so much Akrun- This fixed it! As always,  your knowledge and intuition amaze me!!

Comment: thank you.  I think it is better always to use `[[` which is more generall in subsettting.  Probably you have created the function tested while working on data.frame and this caused the bug when the class got changed to tibble/data.table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the OP's original dataset is either `tibble` or `data.table` because both of them doesn't subset the columns into a `vector` when we do `, column` as it is `drop = FALSE` in both when compared to `data.frame` (which is `drop = TRUE`)

```
> compute_treatment_effects(as_tibble(dataset), outcome, baseline_outcome, covariates, standardize = TRUE)
```

> Error in is.data.frame(x) :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In mean.default(dataset[dataset$treat == 0, outcome], na.rm = TRUE) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

---

The fix would be to either convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`

```
compute_treatment_effects(as.data.frame(dataset), outcome, baseline_outcome, covariates, standardize = TRUE)
```

-output

```
var1 Var2 var3  var4 cov1 cov2  cov3 treatment_group treat
1     2 -Inf    2    21   22 2322  2552             trt     1
2     1   NA    2 26656   NA   42 53542             trt     1
3    10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
4    10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
5    10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
6    10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
7    10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
8    10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
9    10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
10   10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
11   10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
12   10  NaN   10    10   10   10    10         control     0
```

Or make the changes in the function by using `[[` instead of `[` for subsetting the column i.e.

```
compute_treatment_effects <- function(dataset, outcome, baseline_outcome, 
                                       covariates, 
                                       standardize){
  
  
   baseline_covariates <- c(baseline_outcome, covariates)
  
    
   dataset <- dataset %>%
     mutate(treat =ifelse(treatment_group == "trt", 1, 
                            ifelse(treatment_group == "control", 0, NA))) %>%
     filter(!is.na(treat))  
    
   if (standardize){
     dataset[[outcome]] <- (dataset[[outcome]] - 
       mean(dataset[[outcome]][dataset$treat==0], na.rm=TRUE))/
   
       sd(dataset[[outcome]][dataset$treat==0], na.rm=TRUE)
   }
   dataset
 }
```